# Automatically insert username and password to run application in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I want to run a shell script that runs an application. The application prompts the user for a username and password. Is there a way to store and call the username and password in the shell script so that even if a user isn't present, it will run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by adding `-u $UN -p $PWD` where `$UN` and `$PWD` are the username and password. I added the above text at the and of the line calling the app in the shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Completely depends on the application being run. Some applications will take a plain-text command line argument for username and password. Obviously being plain-text, this is not secure, and it's program dependent.

You could in theory use Auto Hot Key to mimic the execution of the application and the typing of the password, but again, this is not secure at all and you could be exposing your user/pass to other apps or in plain-text files. So.. use at your own risk :P

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? Passing username and password to the app's stdin

```
/path/to/application <<'END'
username
password
END
```